# What are "flip cards, the star, the lift, the train and fast forward" in following sentence?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I have a sentence which is about the tools that motivate and inspire people. "The tools include Flip Cards, The star, The train, lmage Diary and Fast Forward to name but a few." I don't understand the meaning of words (are mentioned in title) in this sentence and I also don't understand the general concept of sentence

Comment: Presumably these are expanded on later in the text. Are they not? They're just names (of "tools" or techniques) that most likely bear some resemblance to what they normally (literally) represent.

Comment: Where did you find this sentence? What is the source?  What is the context? Without further information this can't be answered usefully.  Please [edit] to add these three details.